# Images Aren't Loading When Launching Website With Heroku. How Do I Fix This?

Tags: python, django, date, heroku

when I deploy ***my heroku website** everything ***loads up except my [The Website Images](https://anim3-domain.herokuapp.com/)*** you could see everything but  it shows the images as errors I am not sure how to fix this I been stuck with this problem for almost 2 days if you know how to fix it please explain it to me so in the future I could go back and see this and fix my problem ***I literally have all the requirements for my website to be launched with heroku but I am not see the images at all***

my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os


from pathlib import Path


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False # remember to change to false

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['anim3-domain.herokuapp.com']
# 'https://anime-domain.herokuapp.com/'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')


STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

my urls

```
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', include("main.url")),
]
```

my wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for mysite project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

here is part of the error log

```
rWarning: No directory at: /app/staticfiles/
2020-10-10T16:21:57.649046+00:00 app[web.1]: warnings.warn(u"No directory at: {}".format(root))
2020-10-10T16:21:57.649987+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py:115: UserWarning: No directory at: /app/staticfiles/
2020-10-10T16:21:57.649989+00:00 app[web.1]: warnings.warn(u"No directory at: {}".format(root))
```

heres the full error log its in pastebin because its to long stack will view it as error
`https://pastebin.com/fEr8LQk1`

Comment: You haven't ran `python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input`, that's why there are no static files for WhiteNoise to serve see [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#collectstatic-during-builds)

Comment: could you explain further more I have no idea what you just said I have done all the steps on my settings.py what do I need to do on my manage.py thank YoU!

Comment: like what do you mean I need python3 manage.py colletstatic --no-input???

Comment: Please provide your full build log, `python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input` should run during build to collect staticfiles for whitenoise to serve